# Referencing IBOutlet in another View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So, I have been having some major trouble figuring this out and I have searched extensively for a solution but I surprisingly could not find one.  I am attempting to create a multiple page (5, to be exact) Sign-Up for users.

I'll start off by showing you the layout of page 1 and 5 (since solving that issue will solve the issue for page 2-4):

[Sign Up Page #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUADT.png)

[Sign Up Page #5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nretm.png)

As you may see (from the page control dots), I am using a page view controller to allow users to scroll from page to page.  What I am trying to accomplish is giving the user the ability to enter their sign-up information in pages 1-5 before submitting it all at once (which can be located on page 5).

Here is the current code I am using for page #1:

```
class SignUpInfoViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
}
```

Here is the current code I am using for page #5:

```
class TermsOfUseViewController: UIViewController {

let minPasswordCharCount = 6

@IBAction func signUpAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let providedEmailAddress = SignUpInfoViewController().emailTextField.text!
    let providedPassword = SignUpInfoViewController().passwordTextField.text!
    let trimmedPassword = providedPassword.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

    if !(validEmail(enteredEmail: providedEmailAddress) && validPassword(enteredPassword: trimmedPassword)) {
        invalidCredentialsAlert()
    }
    else {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: providedEmailAddress, password: providedPassword) { user, error in
            if error == nil {
                FIRAuth.auth()!.signIn(withEmail: providedEmailAddress,
                                       password: providedPassword)
            }
            else {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

// Email is valid if it has a standard email format
func validEmail(enteredEmail: String) -> Bool {
    let emailFormat = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    let emailPredicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailFormat)

    return emailPredicate.evaluate(with: enteredEmail)
}

// Password is valid if it is not empty or greater than a specified number of characters
func validPassword(enteredPassword: String) -> Bool {
    if (enteredPassword != "" && enteredPassword.characters.count >= minPasswordCharCount) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

In the TermsOfUseViewController class, I am attempting to use the emailTextField and passwordTextField outlets from the SignUpInfoViewController, but I am receiving the following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I debugged the error and saw that the emailTextField property from SignUpInfoViewController is nil and so force unwrapping it will cause the app to crash (Note:  I have correctly connected the IBOutlets to the SignUpInfoViewController, so no issue there).

How can I safely transfer the usage of the IBOutlets from the SignUpInfoViewController class to the TermsOfUseViewController class without it crashing?  In other words, how can I make it to where the IBOutlets are no longer nil when I reference them in the TermsOfUseViewController class?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That is a perfect scenario for `delegate pattern`

```
protocol SignUpProtocol: class { 
   func didProvideUserData(username: String ,password: String)
}
```

In your signup class declare a delegate: `public weak var delegate:SignUpProtocol?`

I am assuming when the user has provided the require info, they need to press some button to go to the next step: Thus in that button you should raise the delegate

```
@IBAction func nextButton(sender:UIButton) {
   guard let username = usernameTextfield?.text, let password = passwordTextField?.text, else { fatalError("textfields were empty") }
     if delegate != nil { // this saying when someone is listening to me, I will expose any method associated to me 
        delegate?.didProvideUserData(username:username, password:password) // passing the username and password from textfield 
     }
}
```

if you don't have a button, then look at `property observer`, where you could have some property

```
var didFulfill:Bool? = nil {
    didSet {
          if didFulfill != nil && didFulfill == true {}
        // here you check if your textfields are sets then raise the delegate
  }
}
```

set this property `didFulfill = when both textfields are not empty :)`

Now in your Terms class, just subscribe to that delegate

```
class TermsOfUseViewController: UIViewController, SignUpProtocol {
     var signUpVc: SignUpInfoViewController?
     override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
        signUpVc = SignUpInfoViewController()
        signUpVc?.delegate = self 
    }

    func didProvideUserData(username: String, password:String) {
      // there is your data 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi!  Thank you so much for commenting.  I am admittedly pretty weak when it comes to delegation patterns, so thank you for getting me a step closer to understanding those.  The user has the ability to flip through the 5 pages and enter their info in any way they please; there will be checks on the UIButton to ensure all of the info is added before passing through. This may not be the right question, but how can assigning this protocol ensure that my text fields are not nil?  I guess I'm mores confused as to why the IBOutlets are nil when I have already connected them through Interface Builder.

Comment: Before going to another Vic you make sure that the textfields are not empty. That's your priority until the provide the needed info they can't go to the next step

Comment: Okay, maybe I need a little more of a walkthrough due to my lack of understanding of the delegation pattern.  A couple things:  5 pages can be accessed through the Page View Controller without pressing a button.  The user can flip through each page seamlessly.  If they want to get to the home page, they'll have to submit the button on the Terms of Use page, which then would check that the user has submitted all fields correctly.  So, with that in mind, what would go into the didProvideUserData method, from what you see thus far?  Also, what would go into the didSet observer?  Thank you.

Comment: so the idea of delegate is how we want to pass data between controllers, where on publish and many can listen... I am sure you've used tableview where you subscribe to its delegate and datasource. I would tell you to a create a side project just with two viewcontrollers and see how delegate help your situation

Comment: Ok!  So, I have done a couple examples and am starting to get a good understanding of the delegate pattern.  I'm stumped on one thing, now.  Where would the IBAction from page #5 fit into the protocol?  That action would be called from pressing the "Submit" button and I'm struggling to see where that would come into play.  I see you have the @IBAction in your example, but to me, that looks like it would only be effective if the action was connected to the sign-up page (page #1), which doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Actually, sorry about that, one more final question.  How could you use a delegate to check against 4 other pages in one protocol?  It sounds like it would work when switching between 2 views but I'm not too sure about more than that.

Comment: they all would be listen to the same delegate

Comment: Okay, cool.  Can you answer the question I asked about the IBAction above?  I think I can accept your answer then, as that should be the last thing to help fix my problem.

Comment: I'd vaguely say that your outlets get cleared or set to nil when the controller gets deallocated

Answer (score 0):

You have to take in account that you don't have all references for all `UIPageViewController`s all the time. That being said, I would suggest either to keep object in `UIPageViewController` with updated information or using **Singleton Pattern** to use it to store info into it and later use it. UIPageViewController are being reused and you might have one before and one after and relying onto having them would be wrong.

You can use UIPageViewController as `self.parentViewController` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for commenting!  Can you please elaborate on keeping the object in the UIPageViewController with updated information?  And how would the Singleton Pattern work when dealing with IBOutlets?